# INSERT INTO TABLE using procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am creating the procedure that will load the data after the last_laoaded date.
I have a table LOAD_DATES with last_load_date column.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE LOAD_DATA 
AS 
last_load_date date;
BEGIN

SELECT LAST_LOAD_DATE INTO last_load_date FROM LOAD_DATES WHERE source='LIMS_ANALYTICAL';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO SAMPLE   SELECT * FROM SRC.TBL1@DBLINK WHERE CHANGED_ON > last_load_date';
```

Does anyone know why this is not working?
It's throwing an error :

```
Connecting to the database db1 222.
ORA-00904: "LAST_LOAD_DATE": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "db1.LOAD_DATA", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 2
Process exited.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no need to use dynamic SQL here.  Your `INSERT` statement can just be part of your procedure.
- I would strongly recommend naming your local variable something other than the name of a column in a table-- that makes it too easy to introduce scope resolution bugs where you intend to reference the local variable but actually reference the column name.  Either that or you'll need to use the procedure name to scope the local variable.

Putting those together, something like this should work

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE LOAD_DATA 
AS 
  l_last_load_date date;
BEGIN
  SELECT LAST_LOAD_DATE 
    INTO l_last_load_date 
    FROM LOAD_DATES 
   WHERE source='LIMS_ANALYTICAL';

  INSERT INTO SAMPLE   
    SELECT * 
      FROM SRC.TBL1@DBLINK 
     WHERE CHANGED_ON > l_last_load_date;
END;
```

If you really want to use dynamic SQL for some reason, use a bind variable.  Your local variable is not in scope for your dynamic SQL statement.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'INSERT INTO SAMPLE ' ||
  '  SELECT * FROM SRC.TBL1@DBLINK WHERE CHANGED_ON > :1'
  USING l_last_load_date;
```

Comment: it's throwing a simple error: table or view does not exist. and all of the tables exist... I have been staring at it for way too long...

Comment: @Angelina - What table is it claiming does not exist?  Do both `load_dates` and `sample` exist in the local database in the schema that owns the `load_data` procedure?  Or do they exist in a different schema?  Are there synonyms in place?  Or do you need to use fully qualified table names?

Comment: For some strange reason it didn't throw error when I put back EXECUTE IMMEDIATE... I left it to run auto tonight, hopefully it will load while I am gone. Thanks for your help @Justin Cave

Comment: @Angelina - Dynamic SQL is not compiled when the procedure is compiled, it is compiled at runtime.  You'll almost certainly get the same error at runtime when this piece of code executes.  One of the reasons that dynamic SQL is discouraged is that it turns compilation errors into runtime errors that are harder to debug.

Comment: yep. you were right. it threw error at run time: "ORA-00904: "L_LAST_LOAD_DATE": invalid identifier" @Justin Cave

Comment: @Angelina - Are you still referencing the local variable in your dynamic SQL?  As I said, if you are using dynamic SQL, you would need to use bind variables rather than putting the local variable inside the dynamic SQL.  But there is still no reason to use dynamic SQL here, that only complicates the problem.

Comment: Yes , like you suggested, I removed that part. other part was, permission issues. Thanks @Justin Cave